# On the proof that for $0<x<1$ there exists a real number $a$ s.t. $x^n < a$

Tags: real-analysis

For $\{x \in \mathbb R\ |\ 0<x<1\}$ there exists a real number $0<a<1$ s.t.

$$x^n < a$$

and this real number depends only on $n$.

I imagine I want to use the Archimedian property of the reals at some point but how would one do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the (independent of $n$) choice $a=1$ always work?

Comment: Actually, if $0 < x < 1$, then we can find a number $a$ that *doesn't even depend on* $n$.  Let $a = 1$.  For each $x \in (0,1)$, $x^{n} < 1$, and that's true for every $n$.

Comment: That leads me to believe you mean you want a number $a \in (0,1)$.  Is that right?

Comment: But for any $a\in (0,1)$ and any $n$ you will find an $x$ so that $x^n > a$ (for example, $x = \left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)^{1/n}$). Thus an $a$ that doesn't depend on $x$ cannot be found in that case.

Comment: So, tell us what is $n$.  Do you allow negative?

Comment: Sorry yes $a \in (0,1)$ but @celtschk already found that it is impossible.

Comment: wouldn't any number $a\in (x,1)$ work?

Comment: @user160110 yes but then it depends on $x$. I guess I have to use total convergence to prove uniform convergence in this exercise I am doing. Thanks to everyone

Comment: But isn't the point that it depends on x? You said that if given an $x$ you can find an $a$. So once you give me an $x$, I can pick any $a\in (x,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. In fact if you set $n$ the function 
$$x\rightarrow x^n$$
Tends to 1 if $x$ tends to 1, so there are no $a<1$ that satisfies your hypotesis

Answer (score 0):

If $x<1$, clearly  $\frac1x > N$ for some positive integer $N$.

So $\frac1{x^n} > N^n> N$.

Again taking reciprocals

$x^n <\frac1{N^n} < \frac1N<1$. So $\frac1N$ is the desired $a$ less than 1.

Comment: I think one problem with your answer is it's not necessarily true that $N \neq 1$.  So you could have $\frac{1}{N} = 1$.

Comment: The inequality are just not correct. If $x >0.5$, $N$ has to be $1$, so $N^n = N$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw. Then things depend on $n$. Let this wrong answer stand for people to see the snag and learn how to avoid a trap.